# AWS Elastic Load Balancer max TCP clients

Tags: amazon-elb

I'm trying to do stress tests on my EC2 servers through an ELB.  When running  client applications that make multiple connections to the load balancer I stop making connections right around 65535 clients.  I am running multiples processes on multiple client machines but the total number of successful clients connecting to the ELB is about 64K.

Is this the limit of the ELB?  Is there a configuration property I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: How many instances are behind the elb?  How many availability zones is the elb deployed in (not the same question as how many az's are the instances in, which is another good question)?  How long did you continue your testing?

Comment: The ELB is deployed across 3 availability zones.  So our initial test was with one instance behind the elb and we weren't getting additional instances.  Once we added a second the ELB started adding additional virtual interfaces.  We saw at least 4 new instances and we were able to get 140K+ clients connected.  Initially we started with just one to make sure the ELB was configured and working.

Comment: Do you/did you have cross-availability-zone balancing enabled in the ELB?

Comment: Would love to know this as well